Difference between ROS 2 Humble Desktop and Source on package "geographic_msgs"
I am new to ROS 2, and I am trying to install Autoware.Universe with ROS 2 Humble on ubuntu 22.04. Everything is well when I tried with ROS 2 Humble Desktop, but once I switched to ROS 2 Humble Source, the error "rosidl_generate_interfaces() the passed dependency 'geographic_msgs' has not been found before using find_package()" jumps out.
I checked the files in Desktop version and Source version, and found that a package named "geographic_msgs" is in the path "/opt/ros/humble/include/" of Desktop version but is missing in the path "~/ros2_humble/install/" Source version.
I've tried to copy the package from Desktop version to the Source version but it doesn't help, and I can't find the source code about the geographic_msgs. Is there any suggestion for this problem? Thanks.

I have also tried "sudo apt-get install ros-humble-geographic-msgs" and it returned with "ros-humble-geographic-msgs is already the newest version (1.0.6-1jammy.20240523.213856)".

Problem SOLVED: you can get the source code from https://github.com/ros-geographic-info/geographic_info/releases/tag/1.0.6 and put the code under path: ~/ros2_humble/src/ros2/common_interfaces.
